# Run GCC on SUSE from separated folder

Tags: c++, gcc, rpm, suse

I'm in SUSE 11.4 without root permissions. I need to use a `gcc` rather than the one that came with the system (4.3). The one I want to use (6.2) is separated in a different folder: `/path/to/gcc-6.2.0`.

Just to avoid possible future problems, I made the following:

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/lib:/lib64:/path/to/gcc-6.2.0/lib:/path/to/gcc-6.2.0/lib64:/usr/lib:/usr/lib64:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
```

At `~` folder, I made a `hello_world.cpp` file and ran the following:

```
/path/to/gcc-6.2.0/bin/g++ hello_world.cpp -o hw
```

Then I got this error:

```
/path/to/gcc-6.2.0/libexec/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/6.2.0/cc1plus: error while loading shared libraries: libmpc.so.3: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

Then, I went after the `libmpc.so.3`. I saw that I depended on `libgmp.so.10`: I went to this [site](https://opensuse.pkgs.org/13.2/opensuse-oss/libgmp10-32bit-5.1.3-3.1.2.x86_64.rpm.html), downloaded the `.rpm` file with `wget` on `~` folder and ran this command:

```
rpm -ivh -r /home/unix/me/foo libgmp10-32bit-6.1.2-2.11.x86_64.rpm
```

Got this errors:

```
error: Failed dependencies:
    /bin/sh is needed by libgmp10-32bit-6.1.2-2.11.x86_64
    libc.so.6 is needed by libgmp10-32bit-6.1.2-2.11.x86_64
    libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.0) is needed by libgmp10-32bit-6.1.2-2.11.x86_64
    libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.1.3) is needed by libgmp10-32bit-6.1.2-2.11.x86_64
    libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.3) is needed by libgmp10-32bit-6.1.2-2.11.x86_64
    libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.3.4) is needed by libgmp10-32bit-6.1.2-2.11.x86_64
    libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.4) is needed by libgmp10-32bit-6.1.2-2.11.x86_64
    libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.7) is needed by libgmp10-32bit-6.1.2-2.11.x86_64
```

**I don't know why `libc.so.6` error, because it's in `/usr/lib` folder (set in the first export command I did on `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` var)**. For `/bin/sh` error, I ran `/bin/sh`, set `export SHELL=/bin/sh` and, again, ran this (now with `--nodeps`):

```
rpm -ivh --nodeps -r /home/unix/me/foo libgmp10-32bit-6.1.2-2.11.x86_64.rpm
```

Now getting this error:

```
error: unpacking of archive failed on file /usr/lib/libgmp.so.10;5aa15ea0: cpio: symlink failed - Permission denied
```

Notice that there's a `Permission denied` there, I think that's because I can't write on `/usr/lib` folder. Maybe changing this folder, unpack elsewhere... if possible, how?

Well, I'm quite lost... I'm newbie in all of this stuff.

**Q: How can I use this `gcc-6.2.0`?**

---

Just a info, `ldd` command at `cc1plus`:

```
linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007fff987bc000)
libmpc.so.3 => not found
libmpfr.so.4 => not found
libgmp.so.10 => not found
libdl.so.2 => /lib64/libdl.so.2 (0x00002b782f503000)
libstdc++.so.6 => /path/to/gcc-6.2.0/lib64/libstdc++.so.6 (0x00002b782f708000)
libm.so.6 => /lib64/libm.so.6 (0x00002b782fa91000)
libgcc_s.so.1 => /lib64/libgcc_s.so.1 (0x00002b782fd0a000)
libc.so.6 => /lib64/libc.so.6 (0x00002b782ff22000)
/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00002b782f2e1000)
```

---

`la` command on `gcc-6.2.0/bin`:

```
drwxr-xr-x 2 pbsadmin pbsusers    4096 Dec 15  2016 .
drwxr-xr-x 8 pbsadmin pbsusers    4096 Dec 15  2016 ..
-rwxr-xr-x 4 pbsadmin pbsusers 2868174 Dec 15  2016 c++
-rwxr-xr-x 1 pbsadmin pbsusers 2862280 Dec 15  2016 cpp
-rwxr-xr-x 4 pbsadmin pbsusers 2868174 Dec 15  2016 g++
-rwxr-xr-x 3 pbsadmin pbsusers 2859868 Dec 15  2016 gcc
-rwxr-xr-x 2 pbsadmin pbsusers   67083 Dec 15  2016 gcc-ar
-rwxr-xr-x 2 pbsadmin pbsusers   67067 Dec 15  2016 gcc-nm
-rwxr-xr-x 2 pbsadmin pbsusers   67087 Dec 15  2016 gcc-ranlib
-rwxr-xr-x 1 pbsadmin pbsusers 1666022 Dec 15  2016 gcov
-rwxr-xr-x 1 pbsadmin pbsusers 1673624 Dec 15  2016 gcov-tool
-rwxr-xr-x 4 pbsadmin pbsusers 2868174 Dec 15  2016 x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-c++
-rwxr-xr-x 4 pbsadmin pbsusers 2868174 Dec 15  2016 x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-g++
-rwxr-xr-x 3 pbsadmin pbsusers 2859868 Dec 15  2016 x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-gcc
-rwxr-xr-x 3 pbsadmin pbsusers 2859868 Dec 15  2016 x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-gcc-6.2.0
-rwxr-xr-x 2 pbsadmin pbsusers   67083 Dec 15  2016 x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-gcc-ar
-rwxr-xr-x 2 pbsadmin pbsusers   67067 Dec 15  2016 x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-gcc-nm
-rwxr-xr-x 2 pbsadmin pbsusers   67087 Dec 15  2016 x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-gcc-ranlib
```

Comment: Do not you need `.` in front of the path? `./path/to/gcc-6.2.0/bin/g++ hello_world.cpp -o hw` note the `.` in front of first `/`.

Comment: No. This path starts on root. If I put the `.`, it does not find the `g++`.

Comment: for executables I beleive `.` is mandatory, `.` means run this executable, in this case `.` does not mean this directory.

Comment: Well, when I run without the dot, the executable runs. With the dot, I get `No such file or directory`.

Comment: Do `cd /path/to/gcc-6.2.0/bin/; la` and post output here.

Comment: Got the same thing... As the `ldd` command shows, the problem is really with the missing libs.

Comment: so change to gcc-6.2.0/bin/ director and do `la`. `la` is the same thing as `ls -la` on SUSE or OpenSUSE. `ldd` is something different.

Comment: `ldd` just proves that `cc1plus` won't run.

Comment: Oh do `ls -la`.

Comment: `ls -la` is on the question.

Comment: Nope la -la should give more details more like this:
https://ipggi.files.wordpress.com/2012/09/ls-output-in-nano.png

Comment: Edited the question.

Answer (score 2):

I do use OpenSUSE, but rarely do I use RPM. Maybe this could help you:

```
rpm  -ivh -nodeps --prefix=/some/other/path/ libgmp10-32bit-6.1.2-2.11.x86_64.rpm
```